# How to customize the "Save Resource" dialog of an ISaveablePart in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dialog

I have an Eclipse application that uses a `ViewPart` as a floating window with buttons/options for what is happening in the editor.

It looks similar to the floating tool windows in GIMP.

Implementing `ISaveablePart` in the `ViewPart` provides a default dialog upon closing the ViewPart with everything I want:  a Yes button for saving, a No button and a Cancel button.

However, I would like to customize that default dialog.

Is that possible?  If so how?

I looked into `ISaveablePart2`, but I just end up with my own custom dialog PLUS the default.   Is there a way to suppress the default dialog in `ISaveablePart2?` If so, that would also be a solution.

For clarity: I'm not married to either of these ideas.  What I ultimately want is a custom dialog box to come up when someone closes the `ViewPart` to ask the user if they want to save the contents of the editor ---> with an option to cancel the closing of the `ViewPart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ISaveablePart2` you should only get your own dialog as long as your `promptToSaveOnClose` method does **not** return `ISaveablePart2.DEFAULT`. So there should be no other dialog if you return `ISaveablePart2.YES`, `ISaveablePart2.NO` or `ISaveablePart2.CANCEL`.

The standard Save Prompt dialog is not customizable.

The code for this is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper`.